# When recovering a drive from within Microsoft BitLocker Administration and Monitoring (MBAM), why are you asked for a reason for recovering the drive?

Tags: windows, bitlocker

When choosing to decrypt a drive via MBAM, I've noticed a combo box that asks the user to choose a reason for decryption - several possible options are listed including a lost PIN. What's the relevance of asking this question - are the decryption reasons stored somewhere central and possible for administrators to view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason is: audit.

You can see the reasons in the audit database, using the reports :

[image: MBAM Admin]

By the way, don't forget that support for MBAM 2.5 SP1 will end in April 2026 and will be replaced by [Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/protect/plan-design/bitlocker-management), on-premises.